# Rails: Different Controller behaviour depending on route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many, parameters, routes

I'm looking for the best practice to solve the following situation:

I've got an "Additive" Model which should be many-to-many-associated with some other models.

Examples:

```
# Meal-Model
has_and_belongs_to_many :additives

# Offer-Model
has_and_belongs_to_many :additives

# Additive-Model
has_and_belongs_to_many :meals
has_and_belongs_to_many :meals
```

The routes are nested in the following way:

```
resources :offers do
  resources :additives
end
resources :meals do
  resources :additives
end
```

So I get URLs like this:

```
/offers/123/additives
/meals/567/additives
```

Both routes lead to the same controller action, which is `additives#index`. In the AdditivesController I check if params are available to choose which data to fetch:

```
class AdditivesController < ApplicationController

before_filter :offermealswitch

# GET /restaurants/1/meals/123/additives
# GET /restaurants/1/offers/123/additives
def index   
  @additives = @additivemeal.additives    
end

def offermealswitch
  if params.has_key?(:meal_id)
    @additivemeal = Meal.find(params[:meal_id])
    @type = "Meal"
  elsif params.has_key?(:offer_id)
    @additivemeal = Offer.find(params[:offer_id])
    @type = "Offer"
  end
end

end
```

Is this the right way to handle that problem? It works very well, but I'm not shure this is the rails way...
Thanks for your answers!

Comment: I think your solution is pretty good untill your `offermealswitch` is not too complicated. But also you can just pass `type` with your route

Comment: OK, I found a way to save even the `@type` instance variable: When I need to know in my controller or view which type is actually handled I check `@meal.class == Meal` or `@meal.class == Offer`. As long as it is that simple it seems as a good solution to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*sigh* switching to answer-space so I can at least add carriage returns and make the code not dumb.

I agree with fl00r's answer, but would add that you'd need to instantiate the object thus:

```
@type = params[:type] 
@obj = @type.constantize.find(params["#{type}_id"])
@additives = @obj.additives
```

Comment: I was thought just in jeneral, so I missed that code is not working :)

Comment: that always happens to me too :)

Comment: Thanks for your answers! Constantize was new to me. But I think I keep my solution to keep the URL as simple as possible. Another type-attribute for something which is already in my URL seems redundant to me.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** with respect to @Taryn East

```
resources :offers do
  resources :additives, :type => "Offer"
end
resources :meals do
  resources :additives, :type => "Meal"
end

class AdditivesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :find_additive

  def index   
    @additives = @additive.additives    
  end

  private
  def find_additive
    @type = params[:type]
    @additive = @type.constantize.find([@type, "id"].join("_")) # or "#{@type}_id", as you wish
  end
end
```

Comment: That would need to be: 
@type = params[:type].constantize ;
@obj   = @type.find(params["#{type}_id"]) ;
@additives = @obj.additives

Comment: @Taryn East, as you can see author needs this `@type` to be a string, so we can't constantize it, or we will need to return it as a string. But this is, actually, doesn't matter. And yes, you're right about my mistake :)

Comment: Have added and updated in my own "answer" (so the formatting doesn't suck as bad)